# In a homogeneous cosmological fluid, which position vector is constant, $\vec{r}$ or $\vec{x}$?

Tags: cosmology, coordinate-systems

This question occurred to me while trying to prove an equation in the context of Cosmology. When I decompose the Newtonian gravitational potential $\Phi$ as the sum of a potential $\phi_b$ due to the background density $\bar{\rho}$ and a peculiar potential $\phi$ due to the fluctuations $\rho-\bar{\rho}$ in the fluid density, we know that if the universe is homogeneous then $\phi=0$. But, if we are working with the equation of motion of a particle of said fluid, is it true that its position $\vec{x}$ in comoving coordinates is constant? Or is the physical position $\vec{r}$ the one that remains invariant? And why?

Comment: "By definition, the comoving coordinate, $\vec{x}$, should be constant, shouldn't it?"